# Magento - Side Cart duplicates in Control panel

Tags: xml, magento

I'm creating a custom theme for magento and I ran into problem...

I wanted the cart to be visible all the time while shopping so I created it via `Local.xml`

Here is the code I've used:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
            <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

But the problem is that when I login to the account the block dublicates, and if I try to remove it via `Local.xml` it removes both...

How can I remove the default block and leave the custom one enabled at all times?

See the image to see what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Which code did you use to remove the duplicate ?

Comment: I used: `<remove name="cart_sidebar" />`

Comment: remove the block in your local.xml and add your custom block after you removed the first ?

Comment: tryed it, but didn't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your own cart block differently than the original one (ie not `cart_sidebar`), so it will always be displayed and you'll be able to use `<remove name="cart_sidebar" />` without removing the two blocks.